# jBoss slowness in a VMWare ESXI Virtual Machine

Tags: jboss7.x, vmware

We have a Java EE application that runs in JBoss 7.1.1, and, we must run it in VirtualMachines (such as VMWare ESXI).

The thing is, when we run our app in the VM, the performance is dropped by 50% approx.

Seems like the GC goes crazy... as far I can tell, when GC runs, it take much more longer
than normal to "end", and block the application meanwhile.

Have anyone else had a experience like that? Any tips, tunning or a light that I can follow?

Thanks in advance.

---

## EDIT

- JVM has Xmx and Xms = 1Gb
- VM has 4Gb RAM
- Ubuntu Server 64
- oracle JVM 64

Comment: Without more details what your configuration looks like it would be hard to help you. What is memory configuration of jvm? how much ram does VM have? what kind of OS(32bit vs 64bit) what kind of jvm (vendor and arch). Without this info question is just too general.

Comment: sorry, I edit the question adding the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that before moving your app to VM with configuration you posted it was running on 32bit system and 32bit jvm and using same jvm parameters.

Trick is that you moved to 64bit with 64bit java but still assigned same amount of heap size for your application, what has happened in reality is that you app now has half the memory available that it used to have.
Every object on 64bit jvm is twice the size of the one of 32bit jvm.

Given configuration you have I would suggest few solutions:

- increase heap size to 2G
- or use [compressed oops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html)
- or install 32bit jvm

Given that your application does not have more than 1.3G assigned it think best performance would be achieved by installing 32bit jvm and running with -Xms1300m -Xmx1300m.

You can go even step futher and have 32bit VM with 32bit linux installation.
64bit jvm is only useful if you need more than 1.3G of heap otherwise it just adds too much overhead.

Also you can run jvm with

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

that will show you what is happening with GC, this can further help you tune your jvm.